# SFMCSdk: Sometimes contact key is not changed

Tags: contact, mobilesdk, android

I've faced an issue when integrated the SFMC SDK for Android (version is 8.0.9). Sometimes contact key is not changed for our users. The chance is 0.2%. The integration code is listed below:

Initialization:

```
SFMCSdk.configure(
    context,
    SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
        pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
            setApplicationId(config.applicationId)
            setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
            setPiAnalyticsEnabled(true)
            setAccessToken(config.accessToken)
            setMarketingCloudServerUrl(config.url)
            setMid(config.mid)
            setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
            setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
                    config.notificationIcon,
                    config::createEntryPendingIntent,
                    null,
                )
            )
        }.build(context)
    },
)
```

Then I set the contact key:

```
SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
    sdk.identity.apply {
        setProfileAttributes(...)
        setProfileId(id)
    }
}
```

Then a user performs some actions and the following code executes:

```
...
// this call works fine
SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk -> 
    sdk.identity.setProfileAttributes(...)
}
...
// this call disappears sometimes
SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
    sdk.identity.setProfileAttributes(...)
    sdk.identity.setProfileId(newId)
}
```

The period of time between these calls is a few milliseconds.
Could you please assist?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you determining that the call is "lost" or not taking affect? Also, do you have an open support case? If not, open one, please.

Comment: Also, why not use the method that lets you set both values at the same time? (ref. https://bit.ly/3JY0PWV)

Comment: I log calls to the SDK and sometimes I see that the call occurs but no any request is sent from the device. Consequently the data is not changed for the contact in the SFMC web interface.
I use these calls (setProfileAttributes, setProfileId) because they are mentioned in the documentation. Is it wrong?

Comment: Where can I open a support case?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/

Comment: There are several ways to do this. I have simply shown you another way. Also, it can take up to 15 minutes for the data to propagate through all the systems. The SDK has a DDoS protection mechanism that might be preventing you from making more than 1 call per minute.

I suspect this is simply an expectation issue.